# How to position a html element under a fixed div

Tags: css, html, css-position

I am trying to position some html elements (particularly h1 and p) under a `position: fixed` div without having to use the `<br>` element, because if the top div gets resized (in height), then it will overlap the `<h1>` and `<p>` element. Since this type of question usually needs code, here it is:

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Home | lobuo</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet-main.css">

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="menuBack">

            <ul id="menuBar">

                <li class="menuItem"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="menuItem" class="subMenuHolder">

                    <a>Projects ▾</a>

                        <ul class="subMenu">

                            <li><a href="pages/minecraft.html">Minecraft projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/mods.html">Minecraft mods/plugins</a></li>
                            <li><a href="pages/webapps.html">Web apps</a></li>

                        </ul>

                </li>

            </ul>

            <a href="https://github.com/lobuo">
                <img class="socialIcon" src="img/Octocat.png" />
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/LobuoDev">
                <img class="socialIcon" src="img/YouTube-icon-full_color.png" />
            </a>

        </div>

        <br><br><br><br>

        <div>
        <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
        <p>This is my website. I know how to code a little HTML and JavaScript. I do not have many projects here yet, but there will be some soon. The website is currently under construction, so don't be too dissapointed if a link doesnt work, or a page doesnt exist.</p>
        <p>If you find something wrong with the website, you can report it as a bug <a>here.</a></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the stylesheet-main.css file:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

#menuBack {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(9, 52, 100, 0.92);
    position: fixed;
}

.menuItem {
    color: #e5822e;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.menuItem:hover {
    color: #ab6122;
    background-color: rgba(48, 95, 147, 0.92);
}

.socialIcon {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f44d4d;
}

h1 {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-family: "andale mono",  "courier new", courier, serif;
    padding: 10px;
}

/* MenuBar dropdown menu came from here: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/ */

#menuBar {
    float: left;
}

#menuBar > li {
    float: left;
}

#menuBar li a {
    display: block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menuBar ul {
    position: absolute;
    list-style: none;
    left: 7.1em;
    display: none;
}

#menuBar ul li a {
    width: auto;
    background-color: rgba(9, 52, 100, 0.92);
}

#menuBar ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(48, 95, 147, 0.92);
}

#menuBar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Which one is the div you are mentioning? Dumping the whole html and css for the page makes it harder to locate and solve the problem than helping, please try to replicate the problem in http://jsfiddle.net or post just the relevant code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `margin-top` of the `div` that you need to be pushed down.

So wrap everything that needs to be pushed down in a `div` with a class name.  Like:

```
<div class="container">
    //everything that needs to be pushed down goes here
</div>
```

Then in your css you can push that whole container down by setting it's margin-top

```
.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that makes the page look very funky... [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wzs00e92s6vei1/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2021.57.49.png)

Comment: Thats because you put the menu/navigation in the div.  Take it out and put it above it.

Comment: Ohhhhh... also, you need to set `top: 0px;` on the fixed navigation.  I wrote an example for you.  **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/kQwhj/)**

Comment: I took the nav-bar out of the div, but it still looks funky... [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ucw3ppwqihbyle/Screenshot%202014-03-29%2022.04.50.png) the body id is what has the `margin-top: 100px;` thing **EDIT:** I didn't notice you wrote a reply when I wrote this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting position to `sticky` instead of `fixed` and  give it a `top: 0px;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31178338)

Answer (score 0):

### CSS solution with no margin/ padding

use `position: sticky` and `top: 0px` for your fixed header. With this, the div will be fixed and also takes its height from the parent so the siblings won't overlap with the fixed div.

```css
.parent {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
}

.content {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Header
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <p>content</p>
     </div>
</div>
```