# Stop collapsing divs with position:fixed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a site in twitter bootstrap and want my `content` `div` to be placed just below my `fixed` header. The problem is that my header has `position:fixed` which takes it out of the flow of the layout and collapses my div so it appears to not have any height. I don't want to add `height`as my header might change height depending on its content.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/7nSss/1/

There is an answer here [How to position a html element under a fixed div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741451/how-to-position-a-html-element-under-a-fixed-div) but I don't want to use `margin` or `padding` as my fixed header might change height.

Comment: Sorry to say; but it's not like your navbar is going to change constantly and the cleanest way is the margin/padding. You can do you JS implementations using jquery's resize event on the window... just know that if you're not creating this the OO way, your JS will just become more spaghetti code. The answer I am referring to is @dborghez answer is what you're looking for if you want a JS implementation; with some tweaking, it'll work how you want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve that:

**CSS way**

Just make a hidden copy of your header and insert it before the content and use `position: static` with `visibility: hidden` on it.

**JS way**

Dynamically get your header outer height and use it for the top margin, like this:

```
var topPadding = elem.outerHeight();
$body = $('body');
$body = $body.css('padding-top', topPadding + 'px');
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the CSS solution. But is this solution really advisable  as my site will have 2 headers which means more bandwidth? liked the solution though :)

Comment: Depends on your markup, if it's a lot of elements it'll add some extra bandwidth, but I don't think it'll go more than 1GB with 1M users per month.
You can also clone your header and just paste it in DOM with jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7nSss/6/)

```
var heightfixed = $(".navbar-header").outerHeight();
$(".content").css("margin-top", heightfixed);
```

If your header change in function of media queries or something else you can simply add `$(window).resize(function() { [your code here] });` to do adapt the margin in function on window resize.

Answer (score 0):

**If your header is fixed and dynamically change the header height, then you need to calculate header height and set it to the content div.**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7nSss/5/)**

**jQuery**

```
var headerHeight = $(".navbar-header").height();

$(".content").css("margin-top" , headerHeight);
```

Comment: I think it's better use .outerHeight ( or .outerHeight(true) ) instead of height, because of the margin/padding

Comment: yeah..it's depend upon your html structure. Used jQuery to calculate header is the main purpose.

Answer (score 0):

### CSS solution with no margin/ padding

use `position: sticky` and `top: 0px` for your fixed header. With this, the div will be fixed and also takes its height from the parent so it won't collapse with its siblings.

```css
.parent {
  height: 50vh;
  overflow: auto;
  background: yellow;
}

.fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background: pink;
}

.content {
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class="fixed">
        Fixed Header
     </div>
     <div class="content">
        <p>content</p>
     </div>
</div>
```